# UiDevice.hasObject method takes too long time in UiAutomator

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I write a auto testcase to test Tiktok

In the testcase, before I switch to next video, I will check the current video type, and do something.

```
Log.i(TAG, "check if it's a vr video")
val byRule = By.clazz("android.view.View").descContains("点击体验VR直播，按钮")
if(device.hasObject(byRule)){
     Log.i(TAG, "vr video")
     device.findObject(byRule)?.click()
    SystemClock.sleep(time*1000L)
    device.pressBack()
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "no")
}
```

the UiDevice.hasObject method will return immediately at first time when this code run, however the second time to run becomes very slow, it's takes about more than 10 secs.

Anyone can tell me why?

[image]

full code is here

```
package com.dvdface.qq.uitestdemo

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.SystemClock
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Surface
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest
import androidx.test.uiautomator.*
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.Before

private const val TIMEOUT = 5000L
private const val PKG_NAME = "com.ss.android.ugc.aweme"


private const val TAG = "TiktokTest"

/**
 * Instrumented test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * See [testing documentation](http://d.android.com/tools/testing).
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class DouYinTest {


    private lateinit var device:UiDevice
    private lateinit var context:Context

    @Before
    fun setUp() {

        // init device
        device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())

        // init context
        context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
        assertNotNull(context)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {

    }

    @Test
    @LargeTest
    fun fastFlingLiveVideos() {

        // launch
        launch(PKG_NAME)

        // click suggestion menu
        gotoSuggestionMenu()

        // fling video
        flingVideo(true, 5, 2*60*60)
    }

    /**
     * watch video by fling gesture
     *  videos have many categories:
     *      short video
     *      fullscreen video
     *      live video
     *      VR video
     *      picture video
     *      ai video
     *      reminder video
     * Params:
     * enter - whether to enter play page by click full screen watch / landscape watch / VR watch
     * time - how long to play in single video, in seconds
     * duration - how long to test, in seconds
     * Returns:
     *  None
     */
    private fun flingVideo(enter:Boolean=false, time:Int=3, duration:Long=14400) {

        val actionsForVideos = listOf<()->Unit>(
            {
                // fullscreen video
                Log.i(TAG, "check if it's a fullscreen video")
                val byRule = By.clazz("android.widget.LinearLayout").descContains("全屏观看，按钮")
                if(device.hasObject(byRule)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fullscreen video")
                    device.findObject(byRule)?.click()
                    SystemClock.sleep(time*1000L)
                    device.pressBack()
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "no")
                }
            },  {
                // live video
                Log.i(TAG, "check if it's a live video")
                val byRule = By.clazz("android.widget.TextView").text("点击进入直播间")
                if(device.hasObject(byRule)){
                    Log.i(TAG, "live video")
                    device.findObject(byRule)?.click()
                    SystemClock.sleep(time*1000L)
                    device.pressBack()
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "no")
                }
            },  {
                // vr video
                Log.i(TAG, "check if it's a vr video")
                val byRule = By.clazz("android.view.View").descContains("点击体验VR直播，按钮")
                if(device.hasObject(byRule)){
                    Log.i(TAG, "vr video")
                    device.findObject(byRule)?.click()
                    SystemClock.sleep(time*1000L)
                    device.pressBack()
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "no")
                }
            },  {
                // picture video
                Log.i(TAG, "check if it's a picture video")
                val byRule = By.clazz("android.widget.LinearLayout").hasChild(By.clazz("android.widget.TextView").text("图文"))
                if(device.hasObject(byRule)) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "picture video")
                        SystemClock.sleep(time*1000L)
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "no")
                }
            },  {
                // ai video
                Log.i(TAG, "check if it's a ai video")
                val byRule = By.clazz("android.widget.TextView").textContains("特效")
                if(device.hasObject(byRule)){
                    Log.i(TAG, "ai video")
                    SystemClock.sleep(time*1000L)
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "no")
                }
            }
        )

        val startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        while((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime) < duration * 1000L) {

            // according to video type , do something
            if(enter) {
                actionsForVideos.forEach{
                    it()
                }
            }

            // next
            fling()

            Log.i(TAG, "elapse ${(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime)/1000}s")
        }

    }

    /**
     * fling gesture
     * Params:
     *  step - steps to fling, more steps more slower, default 6
     * Returns:
     *  none
     */
    private fun fling(step:Int = 6) {

        Log.i(TAG, "fling")
        when(device.displayRotation) {
            Surface.ROTATION_0, Surface.ROTATION_180 -> { Log.d(TAG, "fling in portrait"); device.swipe(500, 1400, 500, 800, step) }
            Surface.ROTATION_90, Surface.ROTATION_270 ->  { Log.d(TAG, "fling in landscape"); device.swipe(1200, 800, 1200, 300, step) }
            else -> Log.e(TAG, "unknown direction")
        }
    }

    /**
     * goto suggestion menu
     * Params:
     *  None
     * Returns:
     *  None
     */
    private fun gotoSuggestionMenu() {

        // click suggestion menu
        Log.i(TAG, "enter suggestion")

        Log.d(TAG, "find first page button")
        device.findObject(By.clazz("android.widget.TextView").textStartsWith("首页").descContains("首页，按钮"))?.let {
            Log.d(TAG, "click first page button")
            it.click()
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "find suggestion")
        device.findObject(By.clazz("android.widget.TextView").textStartsWith("推荐").descContains("推荐，按钮"))?.let {
            Log.d(TAG, "click suggestion button")
            it.click()
            it.wait(Until.descContains("已选中"), TIMEOUT)
        }
    }



    /**
     * launch app by clear Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
     * Params:
     *  package - package to launch
     *  timeout - launching timeout, default 5000 ms
     * Returns:
     *  None
     */
    private fun launch(packageName:String, timeout:Long=5000) {

        Log.i(TAG, "launch app")

        // get launch intent
        Log.d(TAG, "get launch intent")
        var intent = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)

        // intent can't be null
        assertNotNull(intent)

        intent?.apply {
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        }

        // start app
        Log.d(TAG, "launch app by intent")
        context.startActivity(intent)

        // wait app
        Log.d(TAG, "wait app to launch")
        device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(packageName).depth(0)), timeout)

    }
}
```

Comment: by looking into the logs, I found it's caused by this code:

Answer (score 0):

by looking into the logs, I found it's caused by this code:

1. My Testcases use androidx.test.uiautomator
2. androidx.test.uiautomator is a test library, which source code is https://androidx.tech/artifacts/test.uiautomator/uiautomator/2.2.0
3. there is a Configurator class in the androidx.test.uiautomator , can be used to configure running parameters in this library: this Configurator is singleton, we can get its instance by
   Configurator.getInstance()
4. we can change wait time by call setWaitForXXXXTimeout method to change waiting time. What's idle status ? the idle status is that the uiautomator doesn't recevie accessibility events from accessibility service for a while. For some reason, some accessibility events were kept sending to the uiautomator client, it can't enter the idle status, and causes too much time to wait for idle. So we need cut off the waiting time, to speed up auto testcase running speed.

```
    /**
     * Sets the timeout for waiting for the user interface to go into an idle
     * state before starting a uiautomator action.
     *
     * By default, all core uiautomator objects except {@link UiDevice} will perform
     * this wait before starting to search for the widget specified by the
     * object's {@link UiSelector}. Once the idle state is detected or the
     * timeout elapses (whichever occurs first), the object will start to wait
     * for the selector to find a match.
     * See {@link #setWaitForSelectorTimeout(long)}
     *
     * @param timeout Timeout value in milliseconds
     * @return self
     * @since API Level 18
     */
    public Configurator setWaitForIdleTimeout(long timeout) {
        mWaitForIdleTimeout = timeout;
        return this;
    }


    /**
     * Sets the timeout for waiting for a widget to become visible in the user
     * interface so that it can be matched by a selector.
     *
     * Because user interface content is dynamic, sometimes a widget may not
     * be visible immediately and won't be detected by a selector. This timeout
     * allows the uiautomator framework to wait for a match to be found, up until
     * the timeout elapses.
     *
     * @param timeout Timeout value in milliseconds.
     * @return self
     * @since API Level 18
     */
    public Configurator setWaitForSelectorTimeout(long timeout) {
        mWaitForSelector = timeout;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the timeout for waiting for an acknowledgement of an
     * uiautomtor scroll swipe action.
     *
     * The acknowledgment is an <a href="http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html">AccessibilityEvent</a>,
     * corresponding to the scroll action, that lets the framework determine if
     * the scroll action was successful. Generally, this timeout should not be modified.
     * See {@link UiScrollable}
     *
     * @param timeout Timeout value in milliseconds
     * @return self
     * @since API Level 18
     */
    public Configurator setScrollAcknowledgmentTimeout(long timeout) {
        mScrollEventWaitTimeout = timeout;
        return this;
    }



   /**
     * Sets the timeout for waiting for an acknowledgment of generic uiautomator
     * actions, such as clicks, text setting, and menu presses.
     *
     * The acknowledgment is an <a href="http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html">AccessibilityEvent</a>,
     * corresponding to an action, that lets the framework determine if the
     * action was successful. Generally, this timeout should not be modified.
     * See {@link UiObject}
     *
     * @param timeout Timeout value in milliseconds
     * @return self
     * @since API Level 18
     */
    public Configurator setActionAcknowledgmentTimeout(long timeout)
```